# show polyline using asp net and database

Tags: javascript, c#, mysql, asp.net

i'm not familiar about asp net. I try to use my project with ASP Net and database from mysql to show markers. But my problem is that googlemaps can displays the markers, but does not display the polylines. I dont know how source code to create the polyline. Can you help me to show you source code? Thanks before.GBU.

Answer (score 0):

A polyline is a list of points, where line segments are drawn between consecutive points.

Passing parameters to Google Map control in asp.net is given [here](http://www.shabdar.org/asp-net/70-google-maps-control-for-aspnet-part-1.html)

Comment: Thank you. I will to try it